# how to allocate a node using "salloc" through Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, slurm

i want to allocate a node using "salloc" through Python. My code is :

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('salloc -N 1 -p {my partition name} --time=01:00:00 &', shell=True)
```

and it relinquished immediately, i can not ssh the node and do something:

```
salloc: Pending job allocation 1628572
salloc: job 1628572 queued and waiting for resources
salloc: job 1628572 has been allocated resources
salloc: Granted job allocation 1628572
salloc: Relinquishing job allocation 1628572
salloc: Job allocation 1628572 has been revoked.
```

is there a way to solve this? I googled and found nothing.